# Android and reading from MySQL

Tags: android

I found an example that explains how to read data from the database, but I have a question. The example describes a method for the table consisting of two columns. What and where should I change the order so that I can work with a large number of columns?
Part of the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_lala);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
accessWebService();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

// Async Task to access the web
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
  try {
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
  response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
}

catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
 String rLine = "";
 StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

 try {
  while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
   answer.append(rLine);
  }
 }

 catch (IOException e) {
  // e.printStackTrace();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
  "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ListDrwaer();
  }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
  List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("PenzGTU");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("Number");
    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("FIO");
    String outPut = "№ " + number + " " + "FIO:" + name;
    employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
 }
 //*****MAYBE HERE?*****
 private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String number, String name) {
  HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
  employeeNameNo.put(number, name);
  return employeeNameNo;
 }
}
```

Comment: Nowhere. You need to change PHP script that serves for obtaining data from MySQL so if table will have more columns, returned JSON will be bigger and more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I can read you consume a REST based web app that does the mining on MySQL, and you App only reads the JSON that outputs well it gets called.

Said this, you will have to modify you webapp logic to make it return the results you want, as you said more than 2 columns from the DB.

Then you will have to modify your JSON parser to get values from the output in this piece of code that you pasted above.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("PenzGTU");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        String number = jsonChildNode.optString("Number");
        String name = jsonChildNode.optString("FIO");
        String outPut = "№ " + number + " " + "FIO:" + name;

        ....

        //For example 'surname' if your webapp returned this DB Column
        String surname = jsonChildNode.optString("Surname");

        ....

        employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hope it´s clear. If in doubt, just ask.

Good luck!